# What trigger the source of staticxx.facebook.com in Google Analytics?

Tags: facebook, google-analytics

I have been asked about the source/medium from facebook on google analytics, and having trouble to find the answer of source "staticxx.facebook.com".

This article mentioned it's triggered from facebook LIKE or SHARE button. 
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20151221000452AA9ggOD

Anyone has different point of view here? Thanks in advance.